# Heroku one-click-deploy of golang application with docker

Tags: docker, go, heroku, deployment, buildpack

I am quite new to heroku and I want to offer people to easily install my application on their own instance via a "Deploy to heroku" button as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button.

I've now created an `app.json` on my develop branch: https://github.com/scribble-rs/scribble.rs/blob/develop/app.json

```
{
  "name": "Scribble.rs",
  "description": "A multiplayer drawing game for the browser",
  "repository": "https://github.com/scribble-rs/scribble.rs",
  "keywords": ["game", "multiplayer", "ephemeral"]
}
```

However, actually testing the button by calling https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fscribble-rs%2Fscribble.rs%2Ftree%2Fdevelop will result in Heroku running the default build procedure for `go`-projects. However, due to the fact that the resulting binary doesn't contain the resources necessary for running the application, the app will build, but crash on startup.

In order to fix this, I'd need to instead run it with a docker-buildpack. However, I couldn't really find any documentation on this specific usecase, even though it seemed quite general. For deploying via GitHub using the GitHub-connection on the "Deploy" tab of an app, you can specify a `heroku.yml`, which I did: https://github.com/scribble-rs/scribble.rs/blob/develop/heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

However, in case of the on-click-deploy, this file seems to be ignored and what I am supposed to do instead, is to explicitly specify a buildpack via the `app.json`. While I've found some GitHub repositories with docker-buildpacks, I kind of dislike this solution, as I'd have to trust some random repository that could either break or vanish any moment.

What exactly is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Interesting problem. Maybe just fork the repo and also keep a copy safe locally?

Comment: Well, I just can't believe nobody had this usecase before ^^

I also generally don't know how fragile such a buildpack is and whether somebody could do malicious things with it.

But yeah, I assume keeping a copy would be an option, but I'd generally like to avoid using one of those options. Maybe there's generally a better solution to this problem and I just don't see it.

Comment: This is pretty much the only one I found: https://github.com/tslocke/heroku-buildpack-docker/. Sadly it doesn't look like anyone's still keeping that up-to-date and I'd generally like to avoid adding yet another project to my list of things that I have to maintain ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have to specify the `stack` inside of the `app.json`. This wasn't very clear by reading the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#stack

I've set this to:

```
"stack": "container"
```