# "Deploy to Heroku" button with a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, heroku

In my public github repo, I have a `Dockerfile` at the root folder. If I follow exactly [Heroku's Docker deploy guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#getting-started), I can successfully deploy my Docker image on Heroku.

Next step, I want to add a [Deploy to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) on my repo's README. I configured `app.json`, but I don't know how to configure it so that it uses Docker deploy. Right now, Heroku does not detect any language:

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.

            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: The Deploy to Heroku button feature doesn't support Docker, as far as I am aware. It builds from the source code in the repo using one or more buildpacks.

Comment: Ah, too bad. Do you have some source, or a Github issue I can track?

Comment: Nothing that explicitly says "you can't do this", this is just from having tried to do the same thing myself.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can set the app.json "stack" field to "container", and it will build the app using your Dockerfile, e.g.:

```
{
  "name": "Test Docker app",
  "description": "Heroku quick deploy using Docker",
  "stack": "container"
}
```

(Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258492/8846296)